# clearing user data on logout with parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Every time I log the current user out using `[PFUser logout];` It logs out, and goes to the login view that I have set up, but when I log in with another user, the profile view still has the same name as the last user, I'm a little confused since I have the text labels set to this:

```
self.usernameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 230, 288, 21)];
[self.usernameLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
self.usernameLabel.text = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"];
```

Comment: Do you run `self.usernameLabel.text =` again when the user changes? (after logout or after another log in)?

Comment: i currently have it set in viewDidAppear

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to ensure this code is being run again when you return from the login screen? The login is a modal, and this should run if it's in viewDidAppear, but it is worth checking.